# Python regular expression for multiple optional groups

Tags: python, regex

I have a text with similar syntax:

```
1_they 3_lens 2'' adapter (adjective)
1_we need 2_zoom6.0 3_system (adjective)
...
```

I need to split this text into 4 groups:

1. group for all strings beginning with `1_` (e.g. `they`,`we need`)
2. group for all strings beginning with `2_` (e.g. `zoom6.0`)
3. group for all strings beginning with `3_` (e.g. `lens 2'' adapter`, `system`)
4. group for all the things inside the brackets at the end (e.g. `adjective`)

I want to use a single regular expression which should ideally give me `None` for a group in case that group is not found in the line. E.g.:

```
>>> line = "1_they 3_lens adapter (adjective)"
>>> our_match = OUR_REGEXP.match(line)
>>> our_match.groups()
("they", None, "lens 2'' adapter", "adjective")
```

Note that all groups are optional (except the last one in the brackets) and that I also have `` characters to match.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you use named capture groups, then `groupdict().get(...)` will return `None` if it isn't present?

Answer (score 0):

this is not overly elegant but does almost what you want:

```
import re
regex = '1_(?P<one>\w+)|2_(?P<two>\w+)|3_(?P<three>[^\(\)]+)|(?P<bracket>\(\w+\))'

strg = "1_they 3_lens 2'' adapter (adjective)"

match = re.findall(regex, strg)
print(match)
res = [ ''.join(item)  for item in zip(*match) ]
print(res)
```

output:

```
[('they', '', '', ''), ('', '', "lens 2'' adapter ", ''),
 ('', '', '', '(adjective)')]
['they', '', "lens 2'' adapter ", '(adjective)']
```